# Qual seria a melhor maneira de fazer um "texto vertical" em HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber de vocês qual a melhor forma de fazer esses tipos de alinhamento de texto como no exemplo(alinhamento vertical, com letras para cima, "*verticalmente reto*". E *verticalmente alinhado* com a borda de uma DIV torta)
[image: Exemplo de alinhamentos]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usando as propriedades `text-orientation`, `writing-mode` e `transform` você pode obter o resultado que deseja. Exceto no caso do `transform` estas são [especificações](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-writing-modes-3/) recentes, talvez não tendo support para versões antigas dos browsers.

**Observação**:
Estes atributos em alguns browsers se faz necessário o uso do vendor (prefixo).
**Exemplo**: `-webkit-text-orientation: upright;`.

> Veja funcionando aqui no [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devgaspa/hyg8pnrs/).

Referência: [MDN - text-orientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation)

Referência: [MDN - writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode)

Referência: [MDN - transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform)

Referência: [MDN - Vendors/Prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix)

Comment: Muito obrigado devgaspa. Parece muito promissor, apesar de que pelas regências não parecer ser um método cross-browser neh. Mas vou testar ainda. Logo deixo um feedback. Obrigado

Comment: @JonatasAmaral Eu que agradeço, uma observação é que se você for olhar pelo fato dos atributos possuírem vendors, acaba sendo um método cross-browser sim, a regência fica por conta das versões antigas dos browsers que não suportam estes atributos.

Comment: Talvez eu tenha me expressado mal com "cross browser", mas quis dizer, que de acordo com as referencias não seria suportado por todos os navegadores (exemplo no text-orientation: http://imgur.com/OgXiUCv)
Mas acabo de pegar o notebook, e vou testar e brincar um pouco